# Correct way to keep a countdown - android

Tags: android, service, countdowntimer

I want to do a countdown to my "mini game", as does Candy Crash. 
I'm doing as follows, first, I get the current time in milliseconds, then I add the seconds to wait, and finally, rest time added to the current time. **All this works fine.**

```
long currentTime= System.currentTimeMillis();

long addTime = currentTime+10000;

long timeFinal= addTime-currentTime;
```

Then I launch a countdown method, with that time (for this example, 10 seconds)

```
new CountDownTimer(timeFinal, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                text.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);

            }

            public void onFinish() {
                text.setText("done!");
            }
        }.start();
```

at this point **continues working correctly**

My intention is to make it run in the background, using a service, but I encountered two problems: 
If the user stops the service, will miss the countdown. 
If the user reboots the device, will miss the countdown.

Then I thought of doing doing the countdown on a server and request the data from the game ... but what if the user has no internet connection?

Candy Crash overcomes all these obstacles.

can someone help me on how can I do this?

Thank you very much for your help and greetings.

Comment: According to me while user stop service or reboot device at that time you can save your time in local any where like in database and same for internet connection. if it is not available then store in to database or shared preference and retrieve it locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why do you use Sqlite (database) to save data ? its very simple and fast and safe way to do that . with this way you can save data .. did you work SQLite in android ?
after that u should give your count down number and set in your service in start Up with Broadcast reciever .